# Remove Everything after a specific word using R

Tags: regex, rstudio, data-analysis, text-mining

[image]

As the image shows, I need to remove everything after the word "**Please**" irrespective of the `position of word "Please"`.

I tried `regex` to remove everything after "`.`", I need different approach for this

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `sub("Please.*","",a)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regexp (\bPlease\b)(?!.*\1)

https://regex101.com/r/9wWAlG/1